# DB script for oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I have below table structure

[image]

To delete the record user will pass the ID, but we have similar text in Data column all the records should be deleted, for example in the above table if users pass 1, we need to delete 3 records (ID 1,2,3), please help for the single delete query.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i have used 2 queries in a STP, first i am collecting the test in a variable and then in second query i am deleting the records.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID DAT
---------- ---
         1 abc
         2 abc
         3 abc
         4 def
         5 ijk
         6 lmn

6 rows selected.

SQL> delete from test t
  2    where t.data = (select t1.data
  3                    from test t1
  4                    where t1.id = &id
  5                   );
Enter value for id: 1
old   4:                   where t1.id = &id
new   4:                   where t1.id = 1

3 rows deleted.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID DAT
---------- ---
         4 def
         5 ijk
         6 lmn

SQL>
```